# Can't run topojson after installation

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I'm working through Mike Bostock's [mapping tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/). I've followed the instructions, installing v0.10.5 of node and using the npm to install topojson. If I run 'whereis topojson
' it displays 'topojson: /usr/bin/topojson /usr/bin/X11/topojson
'. When I try to run topojson, to format the subunits json as per the tutorial, I get the following error:

module.js:340
    throw err;

Error: Cannot find module './lib/topojson/topology'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/topojson/index.js:4:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: I'm having a similar error. In my case, it Cannot find module 'd3' (I was also unsuccessful using npm to install, and instead grabbed the zipfile in the topjson github repository. (The tutorial looks so straightforward...)

Comment: Please post a log of the `npm install -g topojson` command - it's likely something went wrong there.